# Excel - using a cell reference on another sheet in a RAND formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cross-reference

Does anyone know if it's possible to replace the probability reference in a RAND command with a cell reference to another worksheet?

I am using the basic formula below for weighted randomised text selection. The idea is that I can just drag the cells down to fill out a sheet.

On another sheet, I have created a calculator that adds up the cumulative probability for each entry.

As I have to manually edit the formula to update the probabilities. What would be a time saver is if I could replace the probabilities in the curly brackets with the cell reference from the calculator sheet – ie, {0,Calc!C3,Calc!C4,Calc!C5, etc…

Is that possible? I've tried, but just got errors.

Please be aware: I do not have advanced Excel skills. This is the most complicated thing I've ever attempted in Excel.

**The code**

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(RAND(),{0,0.05,0.15,0.3,0.54,0.74,0.79,0.89,0.99,1}),"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine")
```

[The Workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2tnhmt0sdeonsg/Werewolf%20sept%20generator.xlsx?dl=0) – this is Dropbox link to the actual worksheet. It's geeky: I made it for the Werewolf The Apocalypse role-playing game.

Comment: You just try in this way, `=CHOOSE(H105,G105,G106,G107,G108,G109,{"One","two","Three","Four","Five"})` where in `H105` you can put value between `1` to `5`, excel will return value accordingly from Cell between `G105` to `G109`.

Comment: Is the count of number of probabilities fixed or that varies too. e.g. In this example you have ranging from 0, 0.05, 0.15... thru 1 i.e. total 10 values. Does this count of 10 stay constant?

Comment: Also if RAND() generates a number even lower that the lowest probability value, you could get #VALUE or #NA Error. I guess your probability should start with 0 & end with 1 for formula to always work. Also RAND is a volatile function, so it will keep on recalculating itself with any worksheet change event.

Comment: Rajesh – Thanks, but the cells I need to reference are on another sheet. But if I entered "Sheet!A1" I got errors.

Comment: Pat2015 - The number of probabilities can vary. But I found that setting a probability's weighting to zero effectively meant it didn't get picked. I've set the sheets to calculate manually, so they only update when they're told to.

Comment: @RichardCosgrove, check this one working without any problem with the Sheet reference, `=CHOOSE(E105,Sheet3!C160,Sheet3!C161,Sheet3!C162,Sheet3!C1633,Sheet3!C164,{"One","two","Three","Four","Five"})`. *Your mistake is `Sheet!A1` that you have not added the Sheet number and it should `Sheet2!A1`*

Comment: Rajesh – That formula is not what I need to happen. I need the formula to randomly select text, and select the probabilities from text in another cell in another sheet.  Instead of '(RAND(),{0,0.05,0.15…' I need something like '(RAND(),{0,Sheet2!A1,Sheet2!A2…'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best on what I best understand your question, I suggest a following solution. Do check at your end and confirm if it meets your requirements.

I see that you are looking at Probability as a Range. like 0 - 0.4, 0.4 - 0.65 and so on. The last value shall be automatically 1 as RAND also generates a number between 0 and <1.

In your sheet for example 'Rank probabilities' create a table like this. Hope this is self explanatory, you start with 0 on top and then refer the previous value in original Probability Column in below cells respectively.

[image]

In your main sheet e.g. 'Sept' put the following formula in Cells D2 & below.

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(RAND(),TRANSPOSE('Rank probabilities'!$D$2:$D$7)),"1","2","3","4","5","6")
```

Now from within the Formula Bar press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to create an Array Formula. The formula shall now be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

Copy it Down along the intended rows and then Press F9 to manually calculate.
 TRANSPOSE will do the trick of transposing the vertical colum of probabilities into an Horizontal Array and it will replace your manual array of numbers in your formula.

See the below Screen to GIF snapshot.
Test at your end and confirm if this works for you. In this example only the Sheet 'Sept' Column D is modified to reflect Formula Approach. You can replicate the same for other instances as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you: that's wonderful – it's exactly what I wanted to happen. You have saved me hours of brain-ache from Excel and dice rolling!